# How to splice variable value in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

How to splice variable value in AngularJS

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="steps in data" class="card" style="padding:10px 5px 10px 5px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:20px; background: url(@routes.Assets.at("images/Assets/icon_move.png")) no-repeat right #FAFBFC; background-position : calc(100% - 10px) 50%;">
    {{steps.title}}
    <div class="pull-right"  ng-click="deleteStep(steps);"  style="color:#F26063; padding-right: 40px;">Delete</div>
    <a class="pull-right" ng-click="openAddStep('lg');" style="color:#43C944; padding-right: 20px;">Edit</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.deleteStep = function(steps){
    alert('h');
    for (var i = $scope.steps.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (!$scope.steps[i].value) {
            $scope.steps.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the current index to the delete method and then splice it as below, another option is to find the index of the `data` object by using the indexOf method and splice it

```
<div class="pull-right"  ng-click="deleteStep($index);"  style="color:#F26063; padding-right: 40px;">Delete</div>
```

js

```
$scope.deleteStep = function(index){
                        $scope.data.splice(index, 1);
                    }
```

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {

  $scope.data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $scope.data.push({
      title: 'Title: ' + i
    });
  }

  $scope.deleteStep = function(index) {
    $scope.data.splice(index, 1);
  }
  $scope.deleteStep2 = function(steps) {
    $scope.data.splice($scope.data.indexOf(steps), 1);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="my-app">
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    <div ng-repeat="steps in data" class="card" style="padding:10px 5px 10px 5px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:20px;">
      {{steps.title}}
      <div class="pull-right" ng-click="deleteStep($index);" style="color:#F26063; padding-right: 40px;">Delete</div>
      <div class="pull-right" ng-click="deleteStep2(steps);" style="color:#F26063; padding-right: 40px;">Delete 2</div>
      <a class="pull-right" ng-click="openAddStep('lg');" style="color:#43C944; padding-right: 20px;">Edit</a>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```